# Replacing escape sequences with Sed

Tags: sed

With the following text file, `test.txt`:

```
{\x22order\x22:\x22161332\x22,\x22name\x22:\x22chiller\x22,\x22code\x22:\x22chiller\x22}
{\x22order\x22:\x22161332\x22,\x22name\x22:\x22chiller\x22,\x22code\x22:\x22chiller\x22}
{\x22order\x22:\x22161332\x22,\x22name\x22:\x22chiller\x22,\x22code\x22:\x22chiller\x22}
```

How do I replace occurrences of `\x22` with single quotation marks in Sed?

I've tried this with no avail: `sed -i "s#\x22#'#g" test.txt`

Comment: Try `sed -i "s#\\\\x22#'#g" file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use sed to replace all backslashes with forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852951/use-sed-to-replace-all-backslashes-with-forward-slashes)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30462320/3832970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash to make it literal and you need to use `'\''` to represent a single quote in a single-quote-delimited (which they all should be unless absolutely necessary to be otherwise) string or script

```
$ sed 's/\\x22/'\''/g' file
{'order':'161332','name':'chiller','code':'chiller'}
{'order':'161332','name':'chiller','code':'chiller'}
{'order':'161332','name':'chiller','code':'chiller'}
```